# C++ using copy_if

Tags: c++, copy

I am new to C++ and am trying to use the `copy_if` function:

```
set<Person> people; // contains people objects

set<Person> copyedPeople;

string name = "joe"; // Multiple people with that name

copy_if(people.begin(), people.end(), copyedPeople, Person.getName() == name);
```

The problem is with the `Person.getName()`, it says type name is not allowed?

Comment: getName is most likely not static, and you're trying to call it not on a specific class instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need inserter, plus valid predicate:

```
std::copy_if(people.begin(), people.end(),
             std::inserter(copyedPeople, copyedPeople.end()),
             [](const auto& person){ return person.getName() == name; });
```

I don't know your comparer function for person, but if you use the name, previous answer will at most return 1 person. and `std::multiset` might be appropriate with `equal_range`.

Comment: When i try that it tells me std namespace has no member inserter??

Comment: @HelpMeDoC You have included `<iterator>`?